# Should the ternary operator be used outside of assignment statements?

Tags: javascript

*Edit* This isn't a question of [whether or not the ternary operator is harmful](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28314/ternary-operator-considered-harmful). It's about whether or not there's a consensus about whether or not it should be used outside of assignment statements. */Edit*

Based on a boolean, I want to call one of two different functions (with no return value). I wrote this bit of javascript:

```
(condition) ? doThis(arg) : doThat(arg)
```

Which I think looks cleaner than writing out an if-else statement:

```
if(condition) {
    doThis(arg);
}
else {
    doThat(arg);
}
```

My colleagues strongly believe ternary statements should only be used in assignment statements. I can't find style guides that discuss this, probably because languages like Java and C# don't allow this at all (their compilers require ternary operators to return a value). Should this be considered a bad use of the ternary statement? Why?

Comment: Keep in mind that the Jason Voorhees may be assigned maintain that code of yours.

Comment: @gnat - not a duplicate of that question, which is about general use of ?: in expressions, whereas this is specifically about using it as a replacement for if-else when there is no single value being calculated.

Comment: While I'm in two minds as to the appropriateness of the proposed duplicate, this question is still primarily opinion-based, so I don't see any point in reopening it.

Comment: Why do you think this looks cleaner? Breaking conventions like this is opposite of clean.

Answer (score 12):

Generally speaking, the conditional operator is intended to make an if statement *with a value*. `w = x ? y : z`. Thus, if you're using it for side effects, it's counter-intuitive. Valid, but counter-intuitive; and remember that you're writing code for your teammates to read.

Comment: This seems right. Just about every usage example I find, [including Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) uses the operator to perform conditional assignment.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of cases, that are not assignments, where I find ternary operators useful are:

In function arguments: in my opinion

```
f( e1, .. cond ? em : dm, .. en);
```

is less error prone than

```
if ( cond) f( e1, .. em, .. en); else f( e1, .. dm, .. en);
```

When you want to call one function or another with identical arguments: again I find

```
(cond ? f : g)( /* long and complex argument list */);
```

less error prone than

```
if ( cond) f( /* long and complex argument list */);
else g( /* long and complex argument list */);
```

As I see it the key thing in each case is that the ? form has less repetition.  Repetition opens up the possibility of changing one instance and forgetting to change the other.

Comment: In these cases though, you're still using the ternary operator to return a value, which, according to syrion's answer above, is an expected usage.

Comment: @BobbyA what about void functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where a non-assignment use comes in handy, specifically to call one of two functions.

In a Javascript `Promise`, which operates on two function arguments, `resolve` and `reject`, it is possible to do the following one-liner without violating the intuition of the ternary operator returning a value:

```
((this.inputErrors.length === 0) ? resolve : reject)();
```

To me the above reads cleaner than:

```
if (this.inputErrors.length === 0) {
    resolve();
} else {
    reject();
}
```

---

Note: I know this is similar to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/294644), but hopefully easier to understand.